# Docker in docker: storage-driver not supported

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am building a fedora container in my mac. Inside fedora container I want to run docker.

I am having issue while selecting the storage driver. i.e none is supported.

logs:

```
dockerd 
INFO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.921783500Z] Starting up                                  
INFO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.923583100Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.923705600Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.923956400Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.924137200Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.926885300Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.926935900Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.927045600Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.927070100Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
ERRO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.928688500Z] Udev sync is not supported. This will lead to data loss and unexpected behavior. Install a more recent version of libdevmapper or select a different storage driver. For more information, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#storage-driver-options  storage-driver=devicemapper
ERRO[2021-04-26T15:06:14.928746700Z] [graphdriver] prior storage driver devicemapper failed: driver not supported 
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
[root@b13e5800256c /]# dockerd -s overlay
INFO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.608473900Z] Starting up                                  
INFO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.610285500Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.610383700Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.610444000Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.610490400Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.612951600Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.613017100Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.613076400Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.613150300Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
WARN[2021-04-26T15:09:05.615294800Z] [graphdriver] WARNING: the overlay storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release 
ERRO[2021-04-26T15:09:05.618962600Z] failed to mount overlay: invalid argument     storage-driver=overlay
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

Comment: You shouldn't usually want to run Docker in Docker.  Can you say more about what specifically you're trying to do, and why you're trying to run DinD?  How are you launching the container, and what image are you using?

Comment: I am using mac. so I want to build images to my repo using linux env. so container with os fedora.

Comment: Docker Desktop on MacOS runs a hidden Linux VM, and it will normally build and run Linux images.  (Since Docker containers always use the host kernel, you couldn't use DinD to build containers for a different OS in any case.)

Comment: okay. got it ,but still DinD is possible right?